# Connect to NexusDB using Go or PHP

Tags: nexusdb

Im trying to access an applications nexusDB records/tables

I cant find much information on this online, is it possible with Golang or PHP7 and if so is there any documentation on doing so.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP driver (windows only) exists for NexusDB, currently it supports up to PHP v5.x. PHP v7.x support is being worked on.

Other drivers are either ODBC or Ado.NET. Perhaps say more about what you are trying to do?

Comment: I have a client who is using some proprietary accounting software, this software uses nexusdb but it does not allow him to do a bulk import of records, id like to create a script that he can use which will iterate over a directory of xml files and then do insert queries on anything that is not already in the table